# Node.js socket.io webchat moderation

Tags: php, ajax, node.js, socket.io

i have installed the socket.io webchat and I want to add moderation-functionality for the posted comments. Does anyone know how to do that? It should work like when i post a message, the moderator hast du either accept/approve or delete the message. When he approves it, the message will be visible in the chat, otherwise it will not be visible.

any help or suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket.io is more for real time communication. You actually need something between the data sending and receiving. So, I guess that you should avoid the web sockets and store the comments in a database. The moderator then will need to read them and approve/deny. However such implementation is not really good idea when you have a web chat.

You could also try to send the comments to only one user (the moderator). And if he approve the comment just to resend it with a flag *approved*. All the messages which don't have this flag should not be shown.

Comment: why is such an implementation not a good idea?

Comment: That's because you actually need speed. And if you use database that's not exactly the fastest way. You will probably need a lot of space to keep the user's comments.

Comment: ok that makes sense. In this case it will only be used for specific chats, which will last approximately 1hour, so i think it is ok. Thank you very much for your answer(s) :-)

Comment: Also the websockets are heavy in terms of connection, The approach you are trying is good for comments not good for chat.